# How to pass javascript variable to flask url_for which inside innerhtml?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I try to pass JavaScript to `url_for` which is inside `innerhtml` using the below code:

```
var data = 'abc';

mydiv.innerHTML = 
"<button onclick=window.location.href='{{ url_for('flask_function', filepath="+data+") }}'></button>
```

But the result when I print out the data in Python is like this:

```
+data+
```

So how can I pass my data to Flask using this code?

Comment: flask code can be executed in server and javascript code can be executed on browser. You should use js code to update the `href` just after page load.

Answer (score 0):

Would like to put this in comment.

You missed an " at the end.

Also otherwise this will not work because this is rendered in Jinja template python while generating code that has to be sent of the frontend. So it does not recognize js variables.

You will have to use a python variable with jinja template instead

```
{% set data = 'abc' %}
```

Or send the data in template and use

```
{{data}}
```

Comment: thank for response, i have try with your code but it doesn't work, it still send `"+data+"` to python.

Answer (score -1):

you can use like this worked for me
var actualUrl = "/flask_function/" + id + ""
  post.innerHTML =''